# home encryption - how does it work with different users / passwords?

Tags: ecryptfs

In Ubuntu 16.04 you have the option of encrypting the /home/$USER directory with ecryptfs just by ticking a box at install time. /home/$USER is unlocked seamlessly when you log in. The install process tells you that this key is encrypted using your $USER password

If I change my user password using "sudo passwd" will the decrypt keys be automatically re-encrypted? What if I do it from a different account like "sudo passwd $USER"?

Comment: The method with encrypted home and swap is deprecated (after problems to keep things secret with that method). Instead I suggest that you use LVM with LUKS encryption. Does the following solve your problem? [Install Ubuntu 19.10 with encrypted swap/home partitions, specifying manually the swap partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195949/install-ubuntu-19-10-with-encrypted-swap-home-partitions-specifying-manually-th)

Comment: I ran into trouble with it on upgrades: https://askubuntu.com/a/1024754/243321