# Failure when recovering from hibernation with encrypted drive on Ubuntu 20.04. Swapfile priority?

Tags: encryption, swap, hibernate

I used to hibernate on my laptop whose disk is encrypted, under Ubuntu 20.04, following the instruction given in [Install Ubuntu 19.10 with encrypted swap/home partitions, specifying manually the swap partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195949/install-ubuntu-19-10-with-encrypted-swap-home-partitions-specifying-manually-th) and [Hibernate and resume from a swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file) (except that I didn't manage to make it work before Ubuntu 20.04 because of NVIDIA drivers issues...).

But for some times, it does not work anymore: at recovering, after I type my encryption password, it hangs forever.

The first problem that I have is that I don't really know how to "debug" this issue.

Then I wonder if the problem could come from swap priority. When I compare to what is in [Install Ubuntu 19.10 with encrypted swap/home partitions, specifying manually the swap partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195949/install-ubuntu-19-10-with-encrypted-swap-home-partitions-specifying-manually-th), my priorities are in wrong order.

```
root@is241395:~# swapon 
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file       40G   0B   -3
/dev/dm-2 partition 980M   0B   -2
```

It is possible that my problem is due to this. How to update these priorities (I am not sure I understand the relation with `fstab`)?

Answer (score 0):

I can at least answer the question about how to change swap priorities.  You can set this manually in your `/etc/fstab`.  If you want to prefer using your swapfile, edit `/etc/fstab` for the line that contains your swapfile mount.  Looking at your link, it looks like you probably have something in the form of:

```
/swapfile                   none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Change it to:

```
/swapfile                   none            swap    sw,pri=1       0       0
```

Reboot and your machine should prefer to use the swapfile over the partition.